# "error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘a’, which is of pointer type" but I didn't think it was a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays

So, I thought I was trying to do something simple, but apparently not...

I wrote this function so I could extend it later and have a quick way to give the user a menu when required by going `menu(mystrings)`:

```
int menu(string a[]) {
    int choice(0);
    cout << "Make a selection" << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++) {
        cout << i << ") " << a[i] << endl;
    }
    cin >> choice;
    cout << endl;
    return choice;
}
```

But for some reason I get:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int menu(std::string*)’:
main.cpp:38:12: error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘a’, which is of pointer type ‘std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
  int n = a.size();
```

when I try compiling. Could anyone translate that error for me and explain what `->` is, thank you.

Comment: Arrays aren't classes. They don't have member functions. Use `std::array` or `std::vector` depending on your needs.

Comment: I suppose you are doing [`using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: What's with all the downvotes? This isn't unclear, and isn't necessarily a lack of effort/research; it's one of the more awkward things about C++.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you very much, I'm also wondering what I've done wrong, could someone who downvoted please let me know how I could improve my questions in future? I was genuinely confused by the error saying I had a pointer when I hadn't asked for one.

Comment: The `string a[]` in your code is a [syntax quirk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677415/why-do-c-and-c-compilers-allow-array-lengths-in-function-signatures-when-they/22677793#22677793), the code behaves as if you had written `string *a` there.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are passing an array of `strings` and trying to call `size()` on the array. Arrays degenerate to pointers when passed to a function, which explains your error.

The `->` operator, or "arrow operator" (name I use), is just shorthand for `(*obj).func()`. This is useful if you have a pointer to a class object. Example:

```
string *s = &someotherstring;
s->size(); //instead of (*s).size(), saves keystrokes
```

Comment: Not degrade, degenerate. Anyway full on.

Comment: Could I trouble you for some more information? I'm not used to using pointers, how exactly would I use the `->` operator, and does it have a name so I can learn more about it?  Thank you.

Comment: @JamieTwells `string a[]` which you are declaring in function argument, is exactly similar to `string * const a`. By the way, arrays don't have `size` field. So I'm confused what you are trying to get. I think you have to explicitly receive n(number of elements in array) as an argument.   Writing a->size is equivalent to a[0].size which not what you want.