# Is const char array name a const value in a function?

Tags: c

The `s++` is a valid when it is in a function,

```
void f(char s[]) {
  s++; // Why it works here?
}
```

But it isn't when it is in main function. It is wired to me since it has the exactly same data type.

```
void main() {
  char s[] = "abc";
  s++;  // wrong because it is a const value.
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: `char *s[] = "abc";` is invalid -- you're assinging a string (array of `char`) to an array of `char*`.

Comment: sorry, the typo is fixed.

Comment: [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677415/why-do-c-and-c-compilers-allow-array-lengths-in-function-signatures-when-they/22677793#22677793)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because the function parameter `s` is not a character array, but a pointer to a character. You cannot pass an array to a function. What actually gets passed is a pointer to the first element of the array. Arrays are not first-class objects in `C` in this sense. Therefore, the below two function prototypes are equivalent -

```
void f(char s[]);
// equivalent to
void f(char *s);
```

This means `s` can contain the address of any character.

```
void f(char s[]) {
  // s is a pointer to a character.
  // s++ is fine. evaluates to s and
  // makes s point to the next element
  // in the buffer s points to.
  s++; 
  return *s;
}
```

However, the following statement defines `s` to be a array and initializes it with a string literal.

```
char s[] = "abc";
```

Arrays and pointers are different types. The array `s` is bound to a memory location allocated on the stack. It cannot be rebound to a different memory location. **Please note the difference between changing the value of a variable and changing the memory location the variable's name is bound to.** In the above function, you are only changing the content of `s`, but `s` itself always refers to a fixed memory location allocated on the stack.

```
s++;  // in main
```

The above statement in the `main` function evaluates to the base address of the array `s`, i.e., to `&s[0]` and its side effect is to change the content of `s`. Changing the content of `s` means binding the variable `s` to a different memory location which is always an error. **Any variable will always refer to the same memory location during its lifetime. Its content can however be changed but that's different.**

```
int main(void) {
  // s is an array. Arrays and pointers are
  // different types. initialize s with the
  // characters in the literal "abc"

  char s[] = "abc";
  // equivalent to
  // char s[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};

  // illegal operation because s is an array.
  // s is bound to a fixed memory location and
  // cannot be changed.
  s++;
}
```

Comment: +1. Nice explanation. One query, `void f(char s[]);
// equivalent to
void f(char *s);` are they exactly same? Then why to use `[]`?

Comment: @pranitkothari It's just for readability. The compiler *sees* the two prototypes as the same.