# Confusion about argc argv and env

Tags: c++, environment, argv

I just don't know how to explain my question precisely. So I wrote that title above.

Here is my confusion about a very simple program. Exactly, the **results**.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char * tmp[]={"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"};//there are 3 members

int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* env[])
{
    cout << sizeof(env)/sizeof(char*) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(tmp)/sizeof(char*) << endl;
}
```

Results:1  3

What I want is the length of env[]. How can this possible that I got number 1 of env[], while the length of 'tmp'(3) is absolutely rigth.

There's no way that the length of env is 1, cause I tested it and the number is 47.

Why this happened? 
Thanks!

Comment: `tmp` is array, `env` is pointer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I determine the size of my array in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that `tmp` is an array, whereas `env` is a pointer. Arrays and pointers are different. It's a bit confusing because [array syntax in a function formal parameter list is actually a pointer in disguise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677415/why-do-c-and-c-compilers-allow-array-lengths-in-function-signatures-when-they/22677793).

There is no way to get the number of elements pointed to by `env` using `sizeof`. You have to go through them until you find the `NULL` element terminating the list.

Comment: Thx! I did go through them until find the null. Now I am aware that the defination of env is char**. I thought it should be char* env[].

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to remember is that `argv` and `env` are *pointers*, not arrays.  In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[]` and `T a[N]` are interpreted as `T *a`, so the types of both `argv` and `env` are `char **`, not `char *[N]`.

The only way to determine how many elements each points to is by iterating through them until you find a NULL pointer:

```
size_t i;
for ( i = 0; argv[i] != NULL; i++ )
  ; // empty loop body

printf( "There are %zu elements in argv\n", i );

for ( i = 0; env[i] != NULL; i++ )
  ; // empty loop body

printf( "There are %zu elements in env\n", i );
```

Answer (score 1):

The language C has certain syntactical features that are convenient for the experienced programmer, but confusing for the new learner. While the syntax `T * X[]` looks the same in your two cases, they actually mean two very different things:

- `int a[] = { 1, 2, 3};` is the same as `int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };`. Here `a` is an array, and the size of the array is deduced from the initializer.
- `void f(int b[])` is the same as `void f(int * b)`. Here `b` is a pointer, and the notation is merely suggestive of the fact that you should call `f` with a pointer to an element of an array. For instance, you could call `f(a)`, or equivalently `f(&a[0])`, or even `f(a + 2)`. But the declarator syntax is purely a cosmetic convenience, and `b` is *not* an array, but a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This has little to do with these being parameters to main, `sizeof` anything is a compile time expression. Obviously, the environment and arguments passed to your program aren't. `sizeof(array)/sizeof(element_type)` is only the length of the array if that array was declared with a static size. Otherwise, `sizeof(array)` will be equivalent to `sizeof(element*)` (and because `sizeof(char**) == sizeof(char*)` you get `1` in your program).