# sizeof operator returns size of pointer instead of array

Tags: c, sizeof

I'm a little confused when I run the code below:

```
int Maxi(int A[])
{
    return sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
}

int main()
{
    int A[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    print("%d \n", Maxi(A));
    return 0;
}
```

And I just get the result `2`. It seems that `sizeof(A)` turns out to be `8`, which is the size of a pointer. I know this may not be a question worthy asking, but I must miss something and I just cannot figure it out right now.

But if I do this:

```
int main()
{
    int A[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    print("%d \n", sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

It's all right then, and I thought it is related to the passage of value between functions, but I'm confused.

Thanks!

Comment: Which compiler you are using ?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 6.x, it should be GCC I think.

Comment: Note that `int Maxi(int A[])` is just another syntax for `int Maxi(int *A)`

Comment: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677415/why-do-c-and-c-compilers-allow-array-lengths-in-function-signatures-when-they/) for explanation of `int A[]` in parameter list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The A array [decays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) to a pointer once you pass it as a parameter to a function. Hence it's size gets computed to 8 (I'm guessing you're on a 64-bit system). `sizeof(A[0])` is 4 (an int) therefore that's your 2.

The reason it 'works' inside `main` is that the compiler is able to compute the size directly from your static initialization above.

Comment: It's correct when doing the same in `main`. So how can I do it outside of `main`?

Comment: If you simply try to get the number of elements of your array into the function, how about `int Maxi(int A[], int nelements)` ?

Comment: Yeah, I did it. I just want to figure out maybe other ways to do this elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass an integer array to another function with array name.

```
int Maxi(int A[])
```

is equal to this

```
int Maxi(int *A)
```

syntax.

So whenever you are passing an array to another function you should pass number of elements in that array also.

```
int Maxi(int A[], int elements)
//....
// call should be
print("%d \n", Maxi(A, elements));
```

else it treats array as a integer pointer, and it will return the size of the pointer.

Comment: So no way to compute the size of an array outside the scope of its definition?

Comment: @ray6080 ya exactly! if you want to pass an array means you need to pass its no of elements also

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an array to a function, within the called function, Maxi in this case, the parameter declaration for Maxi as int A[] same as int *A

```
int Maxi(int A[])
```

is equivalent to:

```
int Maxi(int *A)
```

So, an array passed is seen as a pointer within the called function, and size of a pointer is of course not the size of the array within Maxi,so, the size has to passed explicitly as in:

```
int Maxi(int A[], int sz)
{
    return sz/sizeof(A[0]);
}

int main()
{
    int A[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    printf("%d \n", Maxi(A, sizeof(A)));
    return 0;
}
```

This will output 5, as desired