# In C++, whether int a[] and int *a are the same for function definitions?

Tags: c++

For the following function definitions, whether they are in fact all equal? If not, what's the difference?

```
void f1(int *a)
{
    //something to do;
}

void f2(int a[])
{
    //the same as function f1
}

void f3(int a[3])
{
    //the same as function f1
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, they are the same to the compiler.

Comment: @MattMcNabb : yep, can't leave out the fringe cases ;-)

Comment: @MattMcNabb They are actually the same in C++. The discussion you linked applies to C.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Not a fringe case in C++. That was the origin of my confusion in the other, C question.

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks, didn't even think about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function signatures are the same.
You may check this out by naming all functions with one name.

```
void f1(int *a) {}
void f1(int a[]) {}
void f1(int a[3]) {}
```

Your compiler will throw a compile error saying something like "redefinition of void f1(int *)". Now notice this, if you rearrange functions as following:

```
void f1(int a[3]) {}
void f1(int a[]) {}
void f1(int *a) {}
```

You will get the same error message about "redefinition of void f1(int *)", not of "void f1(int a[3])". It is because in C++ there's only a way to pass a pointer to an array and function arguments that look like arrays are just syntax ease to pass pointers.
Also check this out: [Why do C and C++ compilers allow array lengths in function signatures when they're never enforced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677415/why-do-c-and-c-compilers-allow-array-lengths-in-function-signatures-when-they)

Comment: A foot note is that they do get enforced for multidimensional arrays except where the left most one is concerned. Effectively the  left most [] isn't enforced where all others dimensions require a size to be complete. As well those dimensions must match what is passed into the function.