# Are ** and * [] the same?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have this pair of declaration/definition on my Eclipse IDE (in a .h and .hpp respectively):

```
 A( T* [] );
```

and

```
 A<T>::A(T ** p_proc) { ... }
```

The first is an array of pointers, the other a pointer of pointers.
I am confused in that they are interchangeable here; Eclipse complains if I replace the `**` by `* []`, throwing a syntax error. Eclipse does not raise errors when I do the opposite, though.

My question is twofold; are these two notations fundamentally the same? Are `T [][]` and `T **` the same as well?
Why does Eclipse throw a syntax error when the hpp file has a type of `* []`, but not in the header?

Comment: `T[][]` is illegal. `T[][x]` and `T**` are not the same.

Comment: @MattMcNabb; I always thought they were the same when decayed.. :S

Comment: @Brandon distinguish between function parameter lists, and other scenarios. The [function parameter list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677415/why-do-c-and-c-compilers-allow-array-lengths-in-function-signatures-when-they/22677793#22677793) case is a syntax quirk. In other cases, an expression with array type "decays" to a pointer to its first element.  Since a pointer is not an array, this pointer does not decay again.  If there is `T x[6][4];` then `x` (when used in a decay scenario) decays to have type `T (*)[4]` , which does not decay further since it is a pointer, not an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is twofold; are these two notations fundamentally the same?

No, they are not. `T*[]` has type *array of unknown size of pointer to `T`* whereas `T**` has type *pointer to pointer to `T`*. Arrays and pointers are **not** identical in general.

However, declaring a *function parameter* to be of array type is exactly the same as declaring it to be of the corresponding pointer type. If a function parameter is specified to have array type then it's "adjusted" to have the corresponding pointer type. In the same way, `int*` and `int[]` aren't the same type, but when you write a function that takes an `int[]` parameter, it's adjusted so that it takes an `int*` parameter. (Note that this adjustment is suppressed if the parameter is a *reference* to array.)

> Are `T [][]` and `T **` the same as well?

Actually `T[][]` is not a valid type at all. In a multidimensional array type, only the *first* bound may be omitted.

> Why does Eclipse throw a syntax error when the hpp file has a type of `* []`, but not in the header?

Probably because you're writing `T*[] p_proc`. The correct declarator is `T* p_proc[]`.

Comment: You're right O_o I was writing T*[] p_proc. Well observed.

Comment: @TamaYoshi `A(T*[])` is legal too (parameter name can be omitted in the declaration)

Answer (score 3):

They're the same *for parameters* to functions. A function parameter can't have the type "array of T". If you try to declare a function parameter as having a type "array of T", the compiler will (silently) adjust it to "pointer to T".

That's not the case elsewhere though. Just for example, having something like:

```
//filea.cpp
int x[SIZE];
```

and:

```
//fileb.cpp
extern int *x;
```

...will *not* work.

Answer (score 1):

If your Eclipse is not understanding the following case, it's a bug:

```
template<typename T>
struct A{
    A(T **p_proc);
};

template<typename T>
A<T>::A(T *p_proc[]) {}
```

It's [perfectly fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35b05692cac91fb2).

Check question about arrays decaying to pointers to understand it in more detail.