# Interpreting a C++ program (Passing multi-dimensional array to function)

Tags: c++, arrays, function

The below program compiles and runs correctly, but the value `5` in `int sum(int p[5][30][20],int n)` is ignored, why?

```
int sum(int p[5][30][20],int n)
{
    int s=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(int j=0; i<30; j++)
    for(int k=0; i<20; k++)
    s+=p[i][j][k];
    return s;
}

...
int x[40][30][20];
int s=sum(x,40);
```

In the function, it is `int p[5][30][20]`, but for the function call, `x[40][30][20]` is used, yet it works.

I appreciate if help me to interpret it.

Comment: Because the first level of array you pass decays to a pointer, so a parameter like `int a[b]` is really passed as `int *a`. [Near duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26049691/179910).

Comment: What do you mean _"but the value of `5` is ignored"_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outermost loop in the function

```
int sum(int p[5][30][20],int n)
{
    int s=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(int j=0; i<30; j++)
    for(int k=0; i<20; k++)
    s+=p[i][j][k];
    return s;
}
```

iterates from 0 to n where n as it follows from the function call

```
int s=sum(x,40);
```

is equal to 40.

When an array is passed to a function by value it is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. So these function declarations

```
int sum( int p[5][30][20],int n);
int sum( int p[40][30][20],int n);
int sum( int p[][30][20],int n);
int sum( int ( *p )[30][20],int n);
```

are equivalent and declare the same one function.

You may use all these four declarations simultaneously in your program. Though the function itself shall be defined only once.

For example

```
int sum( int p[5][30][20],int n);
int sum( int p[40][30][20],int n);
int sum( int p[][30][20],int n);
int sum( int ( *p )[30][20],int n);

int sum(int p[1000][30][20],int n)
{
    int s=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for(int j=0; i<30; j++)
    for(int k=0; i<20; k++)
    s+=p[i][j][k];
    return s;
}
```

Within the function `p` is a pointer that points to an object of type `int [30][20]` (first element of the original array)

A different situation occurs when an array is passed by reference. For example if your function is declared like

```
int sum(int ( &p )[5][30][20] );
```

then the compiler will issue an error for the call

```
int s=sum(x);
```

because the type of x differs from the array type of the function parameter.