# Why does the sizeof operator return the wrong value when used on an array passed to a method?

Tags: c++

```
int size(int arr1[])
{
int size1=sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(int);
cout<<size1<<endl;
return size1;
}
void main()
{
    int b[]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int size2 = size(b);
    cout<<size2<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<size2;i++)
    {
        cout<<b[i];
    }
}
```

I have put the b[] function into size() and check the size then return value.
however, it just return 1 as the answer.
Can anyone please help me to solve this.

A beginner of C++

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677415/why-do-c-and-c-compilers-allow-array-lengths-in-function-signatures-when-they/

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(arr1)` in the function returns the size of a pointer, not of the whole array.
That´s just how the language is.

You´ve to determine the array size without `sizeof`:
Either pass a second parameter with the number, or fill the array in a way
you can find the end because a certain value is there (and nowhere else)