# Getting the length of an array when passed to another function

Tags: c++

```
int *getNewArray(int arr[]) 
{ 
    int newArray[15];
    int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    std::cout << len;

    return newArray; 
}

int main() 
{ 
    int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};    
    int * newArr = getNewArray(arr);

    return 0; 
}
```

Why is the `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` returning me `2` instead of `3`? What is the right way to get the length of the passed array?

Comment: You can not get the length of an array once it has decayed to a pointer. The size is lost. Prefer `std::array` to raw array.

Comment: Unrelated, but you cannot return an array the way you are.  You're going to end up with a dangling reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the sizeof operator return the wrong value when used on an array passed to a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331666/why-does-the-sizeof-operator-return-the-wrong-value-when-used-on-an-array-passed)

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems:

- Firstly, your array has automatic storage. Automatic objects are destroyed automatically at the end of scope. As such, the array no longer exists after the function returns. You return a pointer to the first element of array that does not exist after the function. The returned pointer is always invalid and therefore useless.
- Secondly, there is no general way to know the size of the pointer based on a pointer to element of that array. Typically, you would pass the size of the array along with the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof(arr) = 8 (on 64 bit system). Its a plain pointer

sizeof(arr[0]0 = 4 (if int is 32 bit)

hence the 2.

use std::vector or std::array

Answer (score 0):

I guess the **Optimized code** will look something like this , maintaining the actual functionality as it is by using ***std::vector***.

> For more details I will recommend this link [Vector in C++.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>
    using namespace std;

    vector<int > getNewArray(vector<int >& arr) 
    { 
      int *newArray = new int[15];//creating an array of size 15 in heap
      int len = arr.size();
      std::cout << len;
      return newArray; 
    }

   int main() 
   { 
      vector<int > arr = {1, 2, 3};    
      vector<int > newArr = getNewArray(arr);
      return 0; 
   }
```