# What is a pointer to an 'array of characters' in C?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, command-line

```
int check_authentication(char *password) 
  // 1
{
int auth_flag = 0;
char password_buffer[16];

strcpy(password_buffer, password);      // 2
   if(strcmp(password_buffer, "brillig") == 0)
   auth_flag = 1;
   if(strcmp(password_buffer, "outgrabe") == 0)
   auth_flag = 1;
   return auth_flag;
}

check_authentication(argv[1]) // Passing a 'Command Line argument'
// ( which is a string in this example) to the check_authentication function.
```

I have two questions reg. the lines labelled 1 and 2 above,

1. The function expects a character pointer as an argument. But we pass a "string" i,e an array of characters as an argument. How ?????
2. The address held by the pointer "password" (that points to a character) is copied to the "password_buffer" array. It makes no sense to me . Pls explain.

Comment: 1) the *type* of a string is `char*`; 2) an expression of `char[]` "decays" to `char*` - the important thing with a C string is the object the *pointer refers to* is a valid string: the sequence of characters "in memory" terminated with a '\0' ..

Comment: Note aside from providing a prime target for a buffer overflow, `password_buffer` in this code is useless.

Comment: Not only, it also leaves a nice signature in stack in case of crash... With a very secret password...

Comment: Besides all shortcomings in the code, the question is exact.

Comment: So in function declaration u define the function such that it expects a 'character pointer' .During function call u must pass a pointer only rite ? I dont get this only. 

i,e if a function expects int u pass int, if it requires string u pass string,,but in this case it expects a pointer but u pass an array of characters ...???/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The function expects a character pointer as an argument. But we pass a "string" i,e an array of characters as an argument. How ?????

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

When you call

```
strcpy(password_buffer, password);
```

the expression `password_buffer` has type "16-element array of `char`"; since the expression is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, the expression is converted ("decays") to type "pointer to `char`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element.  This pointer value is what gets passed to `strcpy`.

In short, any time you pass an array expression to a function, the function will receive a pointer value. In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[]` and `T a[N]` will be interpreted as `T *a`.

Believe it or don't, Ritchie did have reasons for designing the language this way; refer to [this paper](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.html) for details (look for the section titled "Embryonic C").

> The address held by the pointer "password" (that points to a character) is copied to the "password_buffer" array. It makes no sense to me . Pls explain.

That's not what's happening; what's happening is that `strcpy` is copying the *contents* of the buffer starting at the address given by `password` to `password_buffer`.  Imagine the following memory map:

```
Item              Address                0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
----              -------                ----  ----  ----  ----
"foo"             0x7fffc7cf4b22          'f'   'o'   'o'     0

argv[1]           0x7fffc7cf2670         0x00  0x00  0x7f  0xff
                                         0xc7  0xcf  0x4b  0x22

password          0x7ffffdbe1878         0x00  0x00  0x7f  0xff  
                                         0xfd  0xbe  0x2v  0x22

password_buffer   0x7ffffdbe1880         0x??  0x??  0x??  0x??
                                         0x??  0x??  0x??  0x??
                                         0x??  0x??  0x??  0x??
                                         0x??  0x??  0x??  0x??
```

where `0x??` indicates an unknown/indeterminate byte value.

The command line argument string "foo" is stored at address `0x7fffc7cf4b22`.  Note that in C, a *string* is simply a sequence of character values terminated by a 0-valued byte.  Strings are stored as arrays of `char` (`const char` in C++), but not all arrays of `char` contain a string.

The `argv[1]` expression evaluates to the address of the first command line argument, which is the address of the string `"foo"`, which is `0x7fffc7cf4b22`.  This value is passed to the `check_authentication` function and is stored to the `password` parameter.  Note that `argv[1]` and `password` are different items in memory (they have different addresses), but both contain the same *value* (the address of the string `"foo"`).

The `password_buffer` array starts at address `0x7ffffdbe1880`.  Since it wasn't declared `static` and doesn't have an explicit initializer, the contents of the array are *indeterminate*.

The `strcpy` function copies the contents of the string starting at address `0x7fffc7cf4b22` into the buffer starting at address `0x7ffffdbe1880` until it sees that 0-valued byte.  After the call to `strcpy`, our memory looks like this:

```
Item              Address                0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
----              -------                ----  ----  ----  ----
"foo"             0x7fffc7cf4b22          'f'   'o'   'o'     0

argv[1]           0x7fffc7cf2670         0x00  0x00  0x7f  0xff
                                         0xc7  0xcf  0x4b  0x22

password          0x7ffffdbe1878         0x00  0x00  0x7f  0xff  
                                         0xfd  0xbe  0x2v  0x22

password_buffer   0x7ffffdbe1880          'f'   'o'   'o'     0
                                         0x??  0x??  0x??  0x??
                                         0x??  0x??  0x??  0x??
                                         0x??  0x??  0x??  0x??
```

Answer (score 5):

1. You are passing a character pointer which points to the first character in the string. You aren't actually passing the whole string.
2. The `strcpy` function reads the character being pointed to by this pointer, and then keeps reading successive characters from the next memory location until it encounters a null terminator.

The first argument of `strcpy`, and both arguments of `strcmp`, work in the same way.

Comment: Yeah I get it partially. But if we pass a "string" in other words an array of characters to the function, then y don't we declare the function like this check_authentication(char password[ ]).what is the significance of pointers in the function parameter declaration..I m  confused there.!

Comment: @callyaser [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677415/why-do-c-and-c-compilers-allow-array-lengths-in-function-signatures-when-they/22677793#22677793) for a good explanation of that

Answer (score 1):

Strings are really just arrays of characters that are terminated with a null byte `\0`. The array is the string itself, the char pointer however is the memory location of the zeroth position of the array.

`strcpy` reads characters beginning from the memory location pointed at by the char pointer until it encounters the null termination character.

Comment: The array is a region of storage; the string exists in that storage. (the string might not use up the entire array).

Comment: So in function declaration u define the function such that it expects a 'character pointer' .During function call u must pass a pointer only rite ? I dont get this only. i,e if a function expects int u pass int, if it requires string u pass string,,but in this case it expects a pointer but u pass an array of characters ...???/

Answer (score 1):

1. Array actually isn't passed as such. What gets passed is a pointer to the very first element of the array. A string in C is actually an array of chars with a terminating `NUL` and it's a pointer to its first element that gets passed.
2. You really should read `strcpy` manpage carefully http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy . No addresses ever get copied there. All the function does is taking a string (an array of chars) `password` pointer points at and copy all the chars found at that address up to the `NUL` to the address pointed by `password_buffer` pointer.