# Why can't I do foo({"asd","asd1"}) with foo(char* args[])?

Tags: c++, function

I'm reading C++ Primer and in section 6.2 it says:

> "Parameter initialization works the same way as variable
>   initialization."

Yet when I do:

```
void foo(char* args[]) {return;}

int main() {

char* args[]={"asd","dsa"};  // ok.

foo({"asd","dsa"});          // error.

}
```

Why is that?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: books lie. often to make things simpler, sometimes because the author doesn't know better.

Comment: @CoryNelson to be fair, arrays are a bit of a corner case in C and C++.

Comment: The *initialization* work in the same way. The *declaration*, however, doesn't. In particular, the function parameter `args`'s type is not an array.

Comment: @T.C. I think you are right, since you can't pass an array to a function. It's just a **char.

Comment: @CoryNelson it's pretty much true: parameters are copy-initialized from their argument. OP only got tripped up in this case because of the *adjustment* of array declarators in a parameter list (which happens before the parameter is initialized).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @T.C. pointed out in the comments, the args in the function argument is converted to a char** because functions can't take arrays as an argument. Since you can't do

```
char **asd={"asd","dsa"};
```

the code is illegal. My confusion came from the fact that

```
char* args[]={"asd","dsa"};
char **asd=args;
```

is legal.

Comment: Related reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677415/why-do-c-and-c-compilers-allow-array-lengths-in-function-signatures-when-they

Answer (score 3):

It is generally possible to take advantage of the new initialization syntax and semantics to use anonymous arrays as arguments, but you will have to jump through a few hoops. For example

```
typedef const char *CC2[2];

void foo(const CC2 &a) {}

int main() {
  foo({ "asd", "dsa" });
}
```

However, in your case this technique will not help because you are requesting an array-to-pointer conversion on a temporary array. This is illegal in C++.

```
typedef int A[2];

const A &r = A{ 1, 2 }; // reference binding is OK
int *p = A{ 1, 2 };     // ERROR: taking address is not OK
```

So, if you really want to do something like this, you can do the following

```
template <size_t N> void foo(const char *const (&args)[N]) {}

int main() {
  foo({ "asd", "dsa" });
}
```

but that is not exactly what you had in mind originally.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is that?

First of all in both cases, you need `char const*` because you are working with string literals.

Secondly, `{...}` could work if the parameter type was an array, but `char*[]` is *adjusted* to `char**` (due to decayment) which cannot be initialised with a *braced-init-list*.

---

Alternatively use `std::string` and `std::vector`, as you are already supposed to do:

```
void foo(std::vector<std::string> args) {return;}
```

and:

```
foo({"asd","dsa"});
```

will [work just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe550311a1d8c1fb).

Comment: You're saying `{...}` is deduced to a `std::initializer_list` when that is never the case when initializing non-class types (and not deducing from `auto`). And no, the parameter type is not `T[]`. The declaration is *adjusted* to `T*` and the argument (if an array) will be implicitly converted.

Comment: I'm using Visual C++ 2010 and it doesn't include initializer_list.

Answer (score 0):

> "Parameter initialization works the same way as variable initialization."

This is true as far as calling constructors, I think they mean.  However, initializers are special, and different from ordinary value expressions you can assign to a variable or pass to a function call.

C/C++ doesn't have a way to write a literal anonymous array.  You can only do it as an initializer as you declare a variable.