# In a function parameter, what is the difference between int *arr and int arr[]

Tags: c++, function

suppose if I pass array by reference and then collect it in an array pointer , 
we can write `int *arr` or `int arr[]`, what is the difference between two ?

Comment: Re-opening. That was not the right duplicate. The issue here is parameter adjustment, not argument decay.

Comment: @juanchopanza how about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677415/why-do-c-and-c-compilers-allow-array-lengths-in-function-signatures-when-they/) ?

Comment: To answer the question: there is no difference, they are exactly the same. Nothing more needs to be said. Also, "pass array by pointer" would be a better description, "reference" means something else in C++.

Comment: What do you mean by "collect"?  Can you add some example code, for the sake of being unambiguous?

Comment: @MattMcNabb That was good but I think I found a better one, in that it asks essentially the same question as is asked here.