# Error in passing 2 dimensional array to function in c

Tags: c, arrays, function

This is a sample of how I tried to pass the array to a function, it is not the actual function used but this one gives the same result. I get incomprehensible numbers whereas if I print the array from the main function it prints just fine. If it's something obvious, I'm sorry in advance but I'm new to using fucntions. Thanks!

I am using the call function:   print(NP,EP,InputArray);

```
void print(int NP,int EP,double InputArray[][EP])
{
    int qw,er;
    for(qw=0;qw<NP;qw++)
    {
        for(er=0;er<EP;er++)
        {
            if(er==EP-1)
            {
                printf("%lf\n\n",InputArray[qw][er]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%lf\n",InputArray[qw][er]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `void print(int NP,int EP,double InputArray[NP][EP])` (notice the dimensions of `InputArray`)?

Comment: @mah that would make no difference  ([outermost dimension is ignored](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22677793/1505939))

Comment: Where is the code that calls `print`?

Comment: This part dosent seem to have any problem .Show calling function .

Comment: This is not "a sample of how I tried to pass the array to a function".  It is the function's definition.  Please post a sample usage of the function to demonstrate "how I tried to pass the array to a function".

Comment: @R Sahu @M.M I have added the call function.

Comment: `printf` `%lf` is wrong, btw.

Comment: @melpomene Why though? If it is indeed wrong then it must be it cause the output resembles that of using the wrong % to refer to it.

Comment: @MichaelK In C89/C90 `%lf` was simply undefined. In C99 it was defined to be equivalent to `%f`, so there's still no point in using it.

Comment: @melpomene But it should still work right?

Comment: @MichaelK Depends on what your C library does with it.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out this syntax doesn't work for codeblocks. Tried DevC++ and works just fine.