# What's wrong with increment operator in pointer array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I just found a little confusion while using increment operator in pointer array.

**Code 1:**

```
int main(void) {
     char *array[] = {"howdy", "mani"};
     printf("%s", *(++array));
     return 0;
}
```

While compiling, gcc throws a well known error "lvalue required as increment operand".

But, when I compile the below code it shows no error!!! Why?

**Code2:**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     printf("%s",*(++argv));
     return 0;
}
```

In both cases, I have been incrementing an array of pointer. So, it should  be done by this way.

```
char *array[] = {"howdy","mani"};
char **pointer = array;
printf("%s",*(++pointer));
```

But, why code2 shows no error?

Comment: Very interesting! My guess is that it considers `char *argv[]` equivalent to `char **argv` but not so with a user-defined pointer to array..

Comment: A local variable `char *array[]` is an array of pointers. A function argument `char *argv[]` is actually a `char **argv`. C11 draft standard `6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes), Section 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’[...]`.

Comment: `char *argv[]` passed to `main()` decays to `char **`, not so with your direct use of `*array[]` in `main()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays cannot be incremented.

In your first code sample you try to increment an array. In the second code sample you try to increment a pointer.

What's tripping you up is that when an array declarator appears in a function parameter list, it actually gets adjusted to be a pointer declarator. (This is different to array-pointer decay).  In the second snippet, `char *argv[]` actually means `char **argv`.

[See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677415/why-do-c-and-c-compilers-allow-array-lengths-in-function-signatures-when-they/) for a similar discussion.