# Incompatible parameter types?

Tags: c, arrays, function

I want to use another function to print the contents of an array.
When I run the code I get "IntelliSense: argument of type "int (*)[3][3]" is incompatible with parameter of type "int *(*)[3]"

This is my function:

```
void display(int *p[N_ROWS][N_COLS]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N_ROWS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <N _COLS; j++) {
            printf("%i", p[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

I defined `N_ROWS` and `N_COLS`
and in my `main` function I declare my array and then call the function

```
{
    int Array[N_ROWS][N_COLS] = { {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9} };
    display(&Array);
}
```

Aren't both my parameters type `int(*)[3][3]` or am I missing something?

Comment: You probably meant the function parameter to be `int (*p)[N_ROWS][N_COLS]`

Comment: Your function is declared to take an array of pointers, and you're passing it a pointer to an array.

Comment: @M.M: I suspect OP just should remove the `*` from `p`.

Comment: Look at the declaration of `Array` and the function argument `p`. Then think what you pass to `p`. (But be aware that the **semantics** differ). An array is not a pointer (and vice versa).

Comment: Remove the `*` from the function, and remove the `&` from the call.

Comment: @Olaf In that case the `&` would also be removed from `&Array`, and also it would be possible to call the function with an array with a different number of rows, silently causing undefined behaviour if not enough rows are given. OP may want the compiler to diagnose attempt to pass an array that is not the exact size of both row and column.

Comment: So I removed the * and & and that error went away, but now it's saying that expression must have a pointer to object type (in my printf statement) 
as well as function returning array is not allowed? (No idea what this means)
@Olaf Array is declared as a 3x3 array, if I changed the code to 
void display(int p)[N_ROWS][N_COLS] 
wouldn't I  be only referencing for an integer and not an array?

Comment: @vvid solely removing `*` and `&` from the code you posted would not cause that error message. You must have also made some other change. Perhaps you messed with `p[i][j]`.

Comment: Yeah, I also had to change the () so the prototype read
void display(int p[N_ROWS][N_COLS])
I did not have to change with the 
     p[i][j]

Comment: What did you mean by "I removed the `*`" then?  The only `*` in your code was the one in that prototype.

Comment: You pre-last comment is not clear. Something like `void display(int p)[N_ROWS][N_COLS]` is invalid syntax. C follows a strict syntax&grammar. Please be exact what you mean - beginner or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your prototype for `display` is incorrect, as well as your call syntax: you define `display` to take a 2D array of pointers to `int`, whereas you just want a 2D array if `int`, as you pass a pointer to the array in `main` where you just want to pass the array, decaying as a pointer to its first element.

Here is a simpler version:

```
void display(int p[N_ROWS][N_COLS]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N_ROWS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N_COLS; j++) {
            printf("%i", p[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Note however that `p` above can have any number of rows, `N_ROWS` is ignored in the prototype, equivalent to `void display(int (*p)[N_COLS])`.

Note also that your `printf` will output the matrix values without any separation.  This might not be your intent.

And from `main`:

```
{
    int Array[N_ROWS][N_COLS] = { {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9} };
    display(Array);
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason as to why N_ROWS is ignored in the prototype? That's the only thing I find confusing.

Comment: @vvid: the size information for an array specified as a function parameter is not used by the compiler at all, neither for type checking, nor for `sizeof()`, because the array is passed as a pointer to its first element and the size is not deemed to be part of the type. It is accepted for historical reasons: the C inventors did not think of how this would become misleading and error prone. They instead must have thought it was a good way for the programmer to tell the next reader of the code what size is *expected* for the array, which itself is passed as a pointer to its first element.

Comment: @vvid to explain why `N_ROWS` is ignored, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677415/why-do-c-and-c-compilers-allow-array-lengths-in-function-signatures-when-they/22677793#22677793).  Note that the alternative solution suggested by jxh means that `N_ROWS` would *not* be ignored any more, so if you want it to be significant you could consider that approach.

Comment: If you pass an array to `sizeof()`, the size information is not ignored. But, C defines array semantics to mostly allow them to be treated "by reference" so that passing an array to a function doesn't cause tons of data to be pushed onto the stack. Their approach was to define array semantics so that it decays to a pointer type, and this decayed type is what the function uses. So the function parameter looks like an array but is actually a pointer.

Comment: @jxr: indeed *the argument looks like an array but is actually a pointer*, it is very misleading, especially for `sizeof()` and any similar macros to compute the number of elements of this false array.

Comment: @chqrlie how are you making those grey boxes? I try Ctrl+K and 5 spaces but it doesn't turn gray

Comment: @vvid: use the backquotes glued to the text: \`code\` will appear as `code`

Answer (score 3):

> <sub>Much of this has already been explained in comments to your question.</sub>

Your definition of `display`:

```
void display(int*p[N_ROWS][N_COLS])
{
```

This says `p` will be an array `N_ROWS` of array `N_COLS` of pointers to `int`.

When you call `display`:

```
int Array [N_ROWS][N_COLS] = { {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9} };
display(&Array);
```

You are passing in the address of `Array`, thus it is a pointer to an array `N_ROWS` of array `N_COLS` of `int`.

To make the definition of `display` match the way you are calling it:

```
void display(int (*p)[N_ROWS][N_COLS])
{
```

The parentheses make the `*` associate with `p` first. Since `p` is a pointer to an array of array of `int`, getting to the `int` requires an extra dereference:

```
printf("%i\n", (*p)[i][j]);
```

Defining `display` to take a pointer to an array means that the size of the array is bound to the type parameter, and thus `display` knows exactly the dimensions of the array.

An alternative means would be to define `display` to take the dimension of the array as a second parameter.

```
void display(int p[][N_COLS], int n_rows)
{
```

In this case the `p` parameter is a pointer to an array `N_COLS` of `int`. An *array of T* when used in most expressions will decay to a value of type *pointer to T* equal to the address of its first element. Thus, you could call this second version of `display` like this:

```
int Array [N_ROWS][N_COLS] = { {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9} };
display(Array, N_ROWS);
```

The advantage of this second approach is that `display` can work with arrays that have fewer or more than `N_ROWS`. The disadvantage is that it is up to the caller to pass in the right number of rows.

You might think that the following declaration would give you complete type safety:

```
void display(int p[N_ROWS][N_COLS])
{
```

But, the array syntax in C for function parameters cause the size information for `p` to be ignored, and becomes equivalent to `int p[][N_COLS]`, which in turn is treated as `int (*p)[N_COLS]`.

Comment: Your points are correct, but the OP is confused on how to pass a simple 2D array, your explanation just adds to this confusion.

Comment: @user3386109: That would defeat the type checking and allow the calling code to pass, say, an `int [1][3]` array as an argument. If the array size is always the same, i.e. fixed at compile time, it is a much better idea to enforce the sizing by doing the above, i.e. pass a pointer to the entire array.

Comment: @user3386109: C99-specific `static` keyword in array size does not enforce anything in this case. It works as a hint to the compiler, but it does not trigger compile-time size checking. If you consider this syntax "complicated", you can always greatly simplify it by using an intermediate `typedef` for array type. Just do `typedef int A[N_ROWS][N_COLS]` and then declare `A *` parameter.

Comment: @jxr: as noted by AnT, your approach does improve type checking, but you must also correct the OP's code and use `printf("%i", (*p)[i][j]);`

Comment: @jxr: for completeness, you might also add the generalized C99 syntax `void display(int n_rows, int n_cols, int p[nrows][n_cols])`

Comment: @chqrlie: C.2011 makes VLA an optional feature. I think that means the array syntax support you are advising is also optional.

Comment: @user3386109 using the `static` keyword does not enforce the constraint.  It helps the compiler optimize , and the compiler *could* emit a warning; but the standard requires that the compiler still compile the code in either case , and in practice no compilers that I'm aware of actually do emit a warning there.

Comment: @chqrlie: A good compiler would warn on the `printf` usage error.

Comment: I understood up to the part about "An alternative means" but the first part was very helpful and agree with the user, it's easier to just remove the * and &

Comment: @jxr: what a bummer! Complete VLA support as specified in C99 was indeed a headache, but making the whole thing optional is killing the feature.

Comment: @user3386109 what compiler? gcc provides no warning. See http goo.gl/XheF1S .  Also it is hard to see why you would advocate a solution where the compiler may optionally warn; vs. one where the compiler must give an error

Comment: @user3386109: Firstly, there's no requirement to generate a diagnostic message in such cases and many compilers don't. I don't know what specific compilers you are talking about. Secondly, and more importantly, a parameter of type, say, `int [static 5]` is supposed to accept argument of type `int *`, i.e. something that is declared as a pointer (not as an array), in which case no compile-time size checking is possible at all.

Comment: @jxr: *A good compiler would warn on the printf usage error.* is a bit of a lame excuse.

Comment: @chqrlie: It's not an excuse, it's the truth. The question was more or less about array function parameters. The `printf` was already broken in the original code.

Comment: @user3386109: You claim I am advocating a particular approach, when that is inaccurate. I am explaining what the asker passed to `display`, and how to make `display` accept that type. Specifically, the last sentence is the actual question: *Aren't both my parameters type `int(*)[3][3]` or am I missing something?*. I explain what is missed.

Comment: That error can be detected trivially within the function by anyone looking at the code, whereas the bounds check error cannot be (and in fact it may not even be known at compile-time what size array is passed in).  A ridiculous comparison by you, really